# How to fix a View on screen inside a ScrollView - react native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I want to set `fixed position` on device screen but inside a `ScrollView` my `View` shows on bottom of `ScrollView`.

my codes:

```
<ScrollView>

  <item />
  <item />
  ...

<View style={{
    position: 'absolute', zIndex: 999, bottom: 0, left: 0, width: 50, height: 50,
    borderRadius: 25, backgroundColor: colorConstants.ONE_APP_COLOR, justifyContent: 'center',
    marginLeft: 10, marginBottom: 10
  }}>
    <Text style={{ textAlign: 'center', fontSize: 28, color: '#fff' }}>+</Text>
  </View>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: But why you need the `View` inside the `ScrollView`?

Comment: It's like a float action button.

Comment: You can keep it outside the `ScrollView` ... no point to keep it inside..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use this type of structure:

```
<View>
   <ScrollView>
   </ScrollView>
   <View>
   </View>
</View>
```

Your scroll view will have different height, based on number of items, it is an overhead to keep the `View` in the `ScrollView`, and probably you will have a lot of bugs and weird behaviors..