# React Native: Text must be withing a <Text> component

Tags: react-native

I just started learning react native today and I'm having a bit of trouble getting a list to render inside a ScrollView. I'm aware that each of the View components inside map should have a unique key, but for simplicity's sake... Here's my code:

```
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, ScrollView} from 'react-native';

export default function App() {
  const numbers = [];
  for(let i = 0; i < 30; i++) numbers[i] = {value: i};
  
  return (
      <ScrollView> {
        numbers.map((num) => {
          return(<View><Text>{num.value}</Text></View>)
        })
      }
      </ScrollView>
  );
  
}
```

I've seen a lot of other posts about it but didn't manage to get it running... Thanks in advance![image]

Comment: Are you getting any errors? What exactly is it that is not working?

Comment: The error is in the title... I’ll edit it with a print of the error too.

Comment: Does it work if you remove the <View> component? Is this helpful to you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52986234/how-to-fix-a-view-on-screen-inside-a-scrollview-react-native?

Comment: No it gives me the same error :(

Comment: Theres a space in <ScrollView> { remove it  <ScrollView>{

Comment: Yes deleting the space makes it work! Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed in a comment by [Guruparan Giritharan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1435722/guruparan-giritharan) the issue is a space.

Instead of:

```
<ScrollView> {
```

It should be:

```
<ScrollView>{
```

Answer (score 0):

have you consider using flatlist? the code would be something like:

```
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, ScrollView, FlatList} from 'react-native';

export default function App() {
  const numbers = [];
  for(let i = 0; i < 30; i++) numbers[i] = {value: i};
  
  return (
      <FlatList
      data={numbers}
      renderItem={item => (<View><Text>{item.value}</Text></View>)}
      keyExtractor={item => item.value}
      />
  );
  
}
```

Also flatlist should not be used inside an scrollview. Good luck.